# Kotlin : FirebaseMessigingService is recive the message, but the notification is not shows

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, kotlin

I create a service extend FirebaseMessiginService, The receive is expected to receive the data notification.

The onMessageReceived is receive data payload well and extract the data correctly. then calling sendNotifcation(). but nothing the notification is not shown.

This is my sendNotification function

```
private fun sendNotification(item: Item) {

    val intent = Intent(this, ItemNotificationActivity::class.java)

    intent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM, item)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
    intent.setAction( System.currentTimeMillis().toString())

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

    //        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channelId")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_new_releases_black_24dp
            )
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(item.title.trim())
                                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel("channelId" + item.id,
                item.title,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    val notification = notificationBuilder.build()
    notification.flags = notification.flags or Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

    notificationManager.notify(item.id /* ID of notification */, notification)
}
```

What is wrong in my sendNotification?

Comment: The problem was in importance, why it's not show if the importance is NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT?

Answer (score 2):

```
 public class MyFireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e("Notification", "From : " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.e("Notification", "Data : " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        String type = remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationType");
        try {
            sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     */
    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String title, message;
        title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        message = "" + remoteMessage.getData().get("text"); //instead of text you can have your key getting received in notification

       // Pending intent will perform redirection on clicking Notification

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                        | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        // Let's create notification to be displayed


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        notiStyle.setSummaryText(message);
        Bitmap remotePicture = null;     // This will be used only when you will have image url in notification and want to display image as a notification.

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION); // incase you want to set your custom sound for notification

        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.app_purple))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

     // If there is an image URL to be displayed, get the bitmap from URL and pass it to notification builder

          if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("image")) {  
                try {
                    remotePicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(remoteMessage.getData().get("image")).getContent());
                    notiStyle.bigPicture(remotePicture);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (remotePicture != null) notificationBuilder.setStyle(notiStyle);
            }

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

      // If you are using device with OS OREO or ABOVE

       if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = "your_app_notificaiton_channel_id";
            CharSequence channelName = "Your App Channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                    .build();

            notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            assert mNotificationManager != null;
            notificationManager .createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }

        notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: I had already added comments for the functions, still if you are not getting something. Let me know the doubt. I will explain it to you.

Comment: Check now. Each line is explained. Still any doubts then please specify

Comment: Should I replace my whole code with yours? And what is wrong with the `sendNotification()` method in question?

Comment: If you will compare few of the properties are missing to get set, will be better if you replace my code with yours and try.

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channelId") For non-Oreo devices also you mentioned such constructor. For lower versions if may not work as well. So I think you should give my code a try

Comment: I don't think this is answered in question's context. Also `NotificationCompat.Builder (Context context)` is deprecated. You can ask OP if he is using non Oreo device for testing, is it a device specific issue or something like that.

Comment: if it is deprecated, it will display a strike out in my android studio 3.1. Also my code is for all devices, so by using that i don't think there will be  a device specific issue.

Comment: What is about mBuilder ?

Comment: That's an object of notification builder.. i had edited answer please check now. There was a typo.

Comment: The problem was in importance, why it's not show if the importance is NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT?